# How to fix 400 error angular + springboot?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, spring-boot

I'm working on an Angular 9 project, and I'm facing a weird problem that took me some considerable time to identify.I am trying to post data into my database but I got error  `error: "Bad Request", message:  "Required request body is missing:`

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/adddonnee 400
```

here is it my code in springboot:
DonneeCourrier  Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DonneeCourrier ")
public class DonneeCourrier {

    private long id;
    private int numOrdre;
    private int refCourrier;
    private int nbDossier;
    private String Bureauordre;
    private Date dateenvoi;
    private Date daterecep;
    private String Modearrive;
    private int Codepostale;
    private String Bureaupost;
    private String Timbrepostal; 
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    } 
    
     @Column(name = "NumOrdre", nullable = false)
    public int getNumOrdre() {
        return numOrdre;
    }
    public void setNumOrdre(int numOrdre) {
        this.numOrdre = numOrdre;
    } 
    @Column(name = "efCourrier", nullable = false)
    public int getRefCourrier() {
        return refCourrier;
    }
    public void setRefCourrier(int refCourrier) {
        this.refCourrier = refCourrier;
    }
    @Column(name = "NbDossier", nullable = false)
    public int getNbDossier() {
        return nbDossier;
    }
    public void setNbDossier(int nbDossier) {
        this.nbDossier = nbDossier;
    }
    @Column(name = "Bureauordre", nullable = false)
    public String getBureauordre() {
        return Bureauordre;
    }
    public void setBureauordre(String bureauordre) {
        Bureauordre = bureauordre;
    }
    @Column(name = "Dateenvoi", nullable = false)
    public Date getDateenvoi() {
        return dateenvoi;
    }
    public void setDateenvoi(Date dateenvoi) {
        this.dateenvoi = dateenvoi;
    }
    @Column(name = "Daterecep", nullable = false)
    public Date getDaterecep() {
        return daterecep;
    }
    public void setDaterecep(Date daterecep) {
        this.daterecep = daterecep;
    }
    @Column(name = "Modearrive", nullable = false)
    public String getModearrive() {
        return Modearrive;
    }
    public void setModearrive(String modearrive) {
        Modearrive = modearrive;
    }
    @Column(name = "Codepostale", nullable = false)
    public int getCodepostale() {
        return Codepostale;
    }
    public void setCodepostale(int codepostale) {
        Codepostale = codepostale;
    }
    @Column(name = "Bureaupost", nullable = false)
    public String getBureaupost() {
        return Bureaupost;
    }
    public void setBureaupost(String bureaupost) {
        Bureaupost = bureaupost;
    }
    @Column(name = "Timbrepostal", nullable = false)
    public String getTimbrepostal() {
        return Timbrepostal;
    }
    public void setTimbrepostal(String timbrepostal) {
        Timbrepostal = timbrepostal;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DonneeCourrier [id=" + id + ", numOrdre=" + numOrdre + ", refCourrier=" + refCourrier + ", nbDossier="
                + nbDossier + ", Bureauordre=" + Bureauordre + ", dateenvoi=" + dateenvoi + ", daterecep=" + daterecep
                + ", Modearrive=" + Modearrive + ", Codepostale=" + Codepostale + ", Bureaupost=" + Bureaupost
                + ", Timbrepostal=" + Timbrepostal + "]";
    }  

Controller: 
public class DonneCourrierController {
    @Autowired
    private  DonneeCourrierRepository donneeCourrierRepository; 
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
     @PostMapping("/adddonnee")
        public DonneeCourrier createDonneCourrier(@Valid @RequestBody  DonneeCourrier donneecourrier) {
            return donneeCourrierRepository.save(donneecourrier);
        } 
}
```

my code in angular:

```
export class DonneeCourrier {
    public id: number;
    public numOrdre: number;
    public refCourrier: number;
    public nbDossier: number;
    public Bureauordre: String;
    public dateenvoi: Date;
    public daterecep: Date;
    public Modearrive: String;
    public Codepostale: number;
    public Bureaupost: String;
    public Timbrepostal: String;
}
```

Html component:

```
<mat-card class="jumbotron"   (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> 
      
        <mat-card-title> Données Courrier </mat-card-title> 
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"> 
          <div class="row" >
      
        
      
          <div class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="numOrdre" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.numOrdre" name="numOrdre">
          </div>
      
          <div  class="col-md-4" class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Email Id</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refCourrier" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.refCourrier" name="refCourrier">
          </div> 
          </div> 

          <div class="row" >
      
            <div  class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
              <label for="name">nb dossier</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nbDossier" default="1" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.nbDossier" name="nbDossier">
            </div>
        
            <div class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Last Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Bureauordre" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.Bureauordre" name="Bureauordre">
            </div>
        
            <div  class="col-md-4" class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Email Id</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateenvoi" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.dateenvoi" name="dateenvoi">
            </div> 
            </div> 
            <div class="row" >
      
              <div  class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
                <label for="name">First Name</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="daterecep" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.daterecep" name="daterecep">
              </div>
          
              <div class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Modearrive" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.Modearrive" name="Modearrive">
              </div>
          
              <div  class="col-md-4" class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Email Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Codepostale" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.Codepostale" name="Codepostale">
              </div> 
              </div> 
              <div class="row" >
      
                <div  class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">First Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Bureaupost" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.Bureaupost" name="Bureaupost">
                </div>
            
                <div class="col-md-4"  class="form-group">
                  <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Timbrepostal" required [(ngModel)]="donneecourrier.Timbrepostal" name="Timbrepostal">
                </div>
              </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  (click)="newdonnerCourrier()" >Submit</button>
        </form>
</mat-card>
```

Component.ts

```
newdonnerCourrier(): void {
  this.submitted = false;
  this.donneecourrier = new DonneeCourrier();
}

  save() {
    this.donneecourrierservice
    .createDonneCourrier(this.donneecourrier).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.donneecourrier = new DonneeCourrier();
     
    }, 
    error => console.log(error));
  }

  onSubmitdonnee() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.save();    
  }
```

service :

```
export class DonneCourrierService {



  private AUTH_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  createDonneCourrier(donne: Object): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(this.AUTH_API + 'adddonnee', donne);
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me to solve this error !

Comment: please show the code where the request is actually done on the client side ... Seems like your client doesn't send a body with the request ... You can also check in the developer tools in the network tab, if the request contains a body, when you hit submit ... (it probably doesn't, thus the error)

Comment: HTTP 400 usually indicates that invalid request was sent. It seems that your endpoint requires some response body - are you sure you are sending that? Remember you can check the Network tab in your browser's Developer Tools and check it in detail

Comment: Hm, the clientside seems ok on a first glance. did you check with the developer tools, that there is really a request body sent with the request?